# jq command throws error "cannot iterate over string" when

Tags: bash, jq

I am writing a bash script utilizing jq to filter out JSON entries given some bash variables and return some of the key values from each entry into a tab-delimited file. I think the first few lines of this command are okay, but the 4th line I think is causing the problem. I have tried piping each entry in line 4 to tostring but to no avail.

```
info=`cat $FILE | jq -r \
    ' .[] \
    | map(select(.host| contains(env.A))) \
    | [."ip.A",."ts",."ip.B"] \
    | @tsv'`
```

JSON example entry:

```
{
  "ts": "2019-06-19T00:00:00.000000Z",
  "ip.A": "0.0.0.0",
  "ip.B": "0.0.0.0",
  "host": "www.google.com",
}
```

In these files, there are no brackets surrounding the entire text within the file.

Error Given:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot iterate over string ("2019-06-18...)
```

Do I need to handle ".ts" in some special way?

Comment: FYI, backtick command substitution is deprecated for good reasons. Much better to run `info=$(jq -r ...<"$FILE")`

Comment: More importantly, the current input isn't valid JSON; it has a `,` before a `}`, so it can't be tested exactly as given.

Answer (score 3):

This code is broken *long* before the 3rd line.

- If there isn't an outer array or object, you can't use `.[]`.
- If your data type is an object and not a list, using `map()` on it throws away data (specifically, it discards the keys, leaving only the values).

...so, `.[]` iterates over the *values* in your object, and then `map()` tries to iterate over each of those values as if it was an iterable object itself, which it's not... hence your error.

---

A version cut down to remove the broken parts might look like:

```
a="google.com" jq -r '
if (.host | contains(env.a)) then
  [."ip.A",."ts",."ip.B"] | @tsv
else
  empty
end
' <<'EOF'
{
  "ts": "2019-06-19T00:00:00.000000Z",
  "ip.A": "0.0.0.0",
  "ip.B": "0.0.0.0",
  "host": "www.google.com"
}
EOF
```

...which works fine.